# Lower Semicontinuity Concepts

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, semicontinuous-functions

Let $X$ be a real Banach space, let $f:X\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a functional. We have known that:

- If $f$ is weakly lower semicontinuous then $f$ is weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous;
- If $f$ is weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous then $f$ is lower semicontinuous.

a) I would like to construct two counterexamples to show that the reverse is not true.

**(It is interesting to find counterexamples in Hilbert space.)**

b) When do these concepts coincide?

Thank you for all help and comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

b) My Google responses on "weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous" query yield something about convexity. For instance, if $X$ is a normed space, and $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb R}$ is quasi-convex and (strongly) lower semicontinuous then $f$ is also weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous [1, Ex.3]. You can try to google for more such facts.

[1] Peter Holthe Hansen, *01716 Advanced Topics in Applied Functional Analysis,*
[Assignment 10](http://www.math.ku.dk/~m07phh/studies/assignment10.pdf).

a) It seems the following.

- An example of a continuous  (and, hence, a lower semicontinuous) function $f:\ell_2\to\mathbb R$ such that $f$ is not weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous. For each point $x_0\in\ell_2$ define a function $f_{x_0}:\ell_2\to\mathbb R$ by putting $f_{x_0}(x)=\min\{\|x-x_0\|-1/3,0\}$ for each $x\in\ell_2$. For each natural number $n$ let $e_n$ be the standard $n$-th ort of the space $\ell_2$. Put $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{e_n}$.
  Then $f$ is continuous as a sum of a family of continuous functions with the locally finite  family of the supports. From the other side, $f$ is not weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous, because $f(0)=0$, but the sequence $\{e_n\}$ weakly converges to $0$ and $f(e_n)=-1/3$ for each $n$.
- An example of a weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous function $f:\ell_2\to\mathbb R$ such that $f$ is not weakly lower semicontinuous.

> Maybe we should first to construct a subset $A$  of the space $\ell_2$ such that $0$ belongs to the weak closure of $A$, but $0$ does not belong to the weak sequential closure of $A$.

I found such a set  $A=\{x_{nm}\}$ in  Bill Johnson’s answer to Question “[A point in the weak closure but not in the weak sequential closure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91217/a-point-in-the-weak-closure-but-not-in-the-weak-sequential-closure)”. The zero is the unique not weakly isolated point of the set $A$. So we may define a function $f:\ell_2\to\mathbb R$ by putting $f(0)=-1$, $f|A\setminus\{0\}=-2$ and $f|\ell_2\setminus A=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Could you help me to find the source of your mentioned fact " sum of a family of continuous functions with the locally finite family of the supports is continuous". Thanks a million.

Comment: @blindman It seems to be easily proved straightforwardly, but it is also should be a corollary of Propostition 2.1.13 of Ryszard Engelking’s “[General Topology](http://webfile.ru/6665165)”.

Comment: The first link is down and I haven't been able to find a replacement.