# How can you prove $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence if $|x_{n+1} – x_n| \le r|x_n - x_{n-1}|$ for some $0<r<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence and let $r$ be a number such that $0 < r < 1$. Suppose that $$|x_{n+1} – x_n| \le r|x_n - x_{n-1}|$$ for all $n>1$. Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I assume this is going to involve the triangle inequality and a substitution somewhere, but the $r$ thrown in is really annoying. Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: The $r$ should not be annoying you - it is in fact your friend!

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I have no idea how. It seems to me that there can always be some r small enough to break this inequality.

Comment: what do you mean? You are *given* such an $r$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: find a bound for $|x_m - x_n|$ that involves a geometric series.

Comment: I would like to ask your comments in the following question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482684/lower-semicontinuity-concepts Thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Show by induction on $m\ge 1$ that $$|x_{n+m}-x_n|\le\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}r^k\right)|x_{n+1}-x_n|\;.$$

Comment: I would like to ask your comments in the following question math.stackexchange.com/questions/482684/… Thank you for your kind help

Comment: @blindman: I’ll give it a little thought, but I probably won’t be able to help: it’s been about $20$ years since I last thought about such things!

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I am still waiting your help.

Answer (score 1):

To show that the sequence is Cauchy, we will be looking at $|x_n-x_m|$, where say $n\gt m$, and trying to get an estimate of its size.

Let $|x_1-x_0|=a$

We have $|x_2-x_1|\le r|x_1-x_0|=ar$

Similarly, $|x_3-x_2|\le r|x_2-x_1|\le ar^2$, and in general $|x_{k+1}-x_k|\le ar^k$.

Now 
$$x_n-x_m=(x_{m+1}-x_{m})+(x_{m+2}-x_{m+1}) +(x_{m+3}-x_{m+2})+\cdots +(x_{n}-x_{n-1}).$$
Taking absolute values, and using the Triangle Inequality, we get
$$|x_n-x_m|\le |x_{m+1}-x_{m}|+|x_{m+2}-x_{m+1}| +|x_{m+3}-x_{m+2}|+\cdots +|x_{n}-x_{n-1}|.$$

Using the inequalities previously established, we conclude that
$$|x_n-x_m|\le ar^m +ar^{m+1}+ar^{m+2}+\cdots.$$
The infinite geometric series has sum $\frac{a}{1-r}r^m$.

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. By picking $N=N(\epsilon)$ large enough, and $N\le m\lt n$, we can make $\frac{a}{1-r}r^m\lt \epsilon$. Thus for such $m$ and $n$, we have $|a_n-a_m|\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: :I would like to ask your comments in the following question math.stackexchange.com/questions/482684/… Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Not my field, it has been a long time!