# Functional weakly lower-semicontinuous

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

If $X$ is a topological space, then a functional $\varphi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is lower-semicontinuous (l.s.c) if $\varphi^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is open in $X$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
If $X$ is a Hilbert space, then $\varphi$ is weakly l.s.c if it is l.s.c on $X$ with its weak topology.

My question: If $X$ is a Hilbert space and $\varphi:X\to\mathbb{R}$, then
$\varphi(x)\leq \liminf{x_n}$ whenever $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ $\Rightarrow$ $\varphi$ weakly l.s.c?

I read this in "A invitation to Variational Methods in Differential Equations". It isn't a exercise, maybe a definition.

Comment: Answered here: [Lower Semicontinuity Concepts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482684/lower-semicontinuity-concepts)

Answer (score 7):

I think the author is being a little sloppy in this paragraph, which raised your question:

[image: statement]

Lower semicontinuity was earlier defined by the openness of upper level sets. The weak topology being non-metrizable, one should not casually insert "in other words" followed by the definition of *sequential* weak lower semicontinuity.

For example, Ciarlet (*Mathematical Elasticity: Three-dimensional elasticity, Volume 1*) is rather clear on this point.

[image: Ciarlet]

I have not seen anyone actually using  weak lower semicontinuity. It's sequential weak lower semicontinuity that's being used all the time, and because of this, many authors  drop "sequential" altogether. Unsurprisingly, confusion ensues.

Unfortunately I do not have an example of a sequentially weakly lsc functional on a Hilbert space that is not weakly lsc.

Comment: There's an example in the "duplicate" question, see my comment above.